# Notification when ancestor view is removed from view in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview

I am specifically interested in a sub UIView getting notification that one of it's ancestor UIViews have been removed from the hierarchy.

I am aware of the callbacks on UIViewController but that doesn't solve the problem of notifying sub UIView's that they have been removed from the hierarchy unless I manually traverse all the subviews and notify them in turn that they are no longer displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass `UIView` and implement method `willRemoveSubview:`.

From Apple Docs:

> Tells the view that a subview is about to be removed.

```
- (void)willRemoveSubview:(UIView *)subview
```

Comment: I want to know when a parent or parent parent ( ancestor ) not child view is removed.

Comment: Do you try to observe `superview` property?

Comment: How would that help if an ancestor 10 levels further up the hierarchy is removed?

Comment: I'm actually not in my dev environment at the moment so I can't try it. However if you have any insight on why such a thing might work that would be appreciated. My understanding is that superview is a property for the direct ancestor and that removing a subview from a superview does not automatically dismantle the entire subtree so there should be no reason that superview would cause a change event. I could be wrong and will try it later but I very much doubt anything will happen.

Comment: Yes, you are right. it will work if all superview will be removed.